# Akka Actor Selection vs Context child

Tags: akka

So seems I have two possibilities to get hold of a child actor instance:

1. By using `context.actorSelection`, which returns a `Future[ActorRef]`

```
context.actorSelection(actorNameString).resolveOne(2.seconds)
```

2. By using `context.child`, which returns an `Option[ActorRef]`

```
context.child(actorNameString)
```

So which one should I prefer and why?

I know what using `actorSelection`, I can be async, but what other reasons exist to favour one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use remote deployment for your child actors (in which case I wouldn't know what to answer), or you want to get a reference to the child of a child, I don't think you should use get an `ActorRef` via `context.actorSelection` to get references to child actors.

`context.actorSelection` is meant to identify and get references of (multiple) actors running anywhere (on other JVMs/hosts) and that's why it is asynchronous. Sure you can use it to get a hold of a child actor, but if you can go for `context.child`.

I think that you can see `context.child` as a specialized version (of `context.actorSelection(actorNameString).resolve`) for cases where you want to get a single reference to a child actor.